# $xy \le xz$ if both $y \le z$ and $0 \le x$. (very easy proof exercise)

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, real-numbers

As an exercise, I tried to prove the following theorem.
Please share your thoughts about what I wrote.
(The proof only uses the utensils which are listed below.)

---

## Theorem

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$.
If both $0 \le x$ and $y \le z$ then $xy \le xz$.

---

## Proof

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$.
Suppose that both $0 \le x$ and $y \le z$.
It remains to prove that $xy \le xz$.

By Definition 1, we have $0 = x$ or $0 < x$.

### Case: $0 = x$

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
            xy
      & =   0y & \quad | \; & \text{Case} \\
      & =   0  & \quad | \; & \text{Lemma 1} \\
      & =   0z & \quad | \; & \text{Lemma 1} \\
      & =   xz & \quad | \; & \text{Case} \\
      & \le xz & \quad | \; & \text{Definition 1} \\
    \end{split}
  \end{equation*}

### Case: $0 < x$

By Definition 1, we have $y = z$ or $y < z$.

#### Subcase: $y = z$

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
            xy
      & =   xz & \quad | \; & \text{Subcase} \\
      & \le xz & \quad | \; & \text{Definition 1} \\
    \end{split}
  \end{equation*}

#### Subcase: $y < z$

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
            xy
      & <   xz & \quad | \; & \text{Lemma 2, Case, Subcase} \\
      & \le xz & \quad | \; & \text{Definition 1} \\
    \end{split}
  \end{equation*}
QED

---

## Utensils

$\textbf{Definition 1. }$
Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.
$
   x \le y \; : \Leftrightarrow \; x = y \lor x < y
$.

$\textbf{Lemma 1. }$
$
   \forall
     x \in \mathbb{R}
   :
     0x = 0
$

$\textbf{Lemma 2. }$
Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$.
If both $0 < x$ and $y < z$ then $xy < xz$.

Comment: ? I'm pretty sure the proof of Lemma 2 already implies this (possibly with a slight modification)

Comment: You need to prove Lemma 2,so this is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You're making this harder than it needs to be. Ordered fields satisfy this:

> **Axiom 1:** $a\le b\implies a+c\le b+c$
>   **Axiom 2:** $0\le a, b\implies 0\le a\cdot b$

Now
$$y\le z\overset{(1)}\implies 0\le z-y\overset{(2)}\implies 0\le x(z-y)=xz-xy\overset{(1)}\implies xy\le xz$$